# To apply validation on radio button and multi select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a form in AngularJS, in that form I have one radio button which has two options and two multi-select I want that form should not get submitted if they are not filled, I want all three of them as required for submitting the form.
I have applied the required keyword of HTML5 in select element but it is not working.

MY HTML Code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label style = "position:relative; left:-170px; top:35px">Params:</label>
    <div style = "position: relative; left: 200px; top: 10px">
        <select multiple chosen class="chosen-select"
                ng-model="recom.recoparams" name="account7" id ="params"
                tabindex="4" style = "width:880px;"
                ng-options = "y as y.paramName for y in params">
          <option value="">--Select--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


    <div>
    <label style =  "position:relative; left:10px; top:20px">Please Choose One:</label>
    <div  style = "position: relative; left: 200px; top:-13px">
    <div>
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="OverallCompany" id="optionsRadios1" name="optionsRadios" ng-model="recom.radio"> OverallCompany</div>
    <div>
    <input type="radio" value="Demographics" id="optionsRadios2" name="optionsRadios" ng-model="recom.radio" >Demographics
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" ng-show="recom.radio=='Demographics'">
    <label style="position: relative; left:10px; top: 28px">Demographics:</label>
    <div style = "position: relative; left:200px">
    <select multiple chosen class="chosen-select" id="demo" ng-model="recom.demo" ng-options = "z as z.demographicName for z in demotype" tabindex="4" style = "width:880px;">
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

So please help me with how can to do it.

Thanks

Comment: required="true" should work

Comment: tried but it is not working, and one of my radio buttons is already checked still when I load the page nither one of them come as checked

Comment: this is working dude

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kga19jhL/ try submitting without selecting any field

Comment: also one of your field is already checked so it is never blank

Comment: @AdeshKumar not working checked

Comment: its working for me check my answer

Comment: But on multi-select, the required is not working,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this is working

```js
function onSubmit(){
console.log("hello")
return
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form onSubmit=onsubmit()>
Male:<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required="true">
<br>
Female:<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required="true">
<br><br>

<select multiple required="true">
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>three</option>
<option>four</option>
<option>five</option>
<option>six</option>
</select><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But on the multi-select, the required is not working.

Comment: I have updated it see its working on multi-select even

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 `required` keyword should work when you put all inputs inside the `<form>` tag and once the submit event is triggered.
You can learn more about client side form validation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)

Comment: I have all my elements inside form tag only

Answer (score 1):

This is your edited code and it is working

```html
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label style = "position:relative; left:-170px; top:35px">Params:</label>
    <div style = "position: relative; left: 200px; top: 10px">
        <select multiple chosen class="chosen-select"
                ng-model="recom.recoparams" name="account7" id ="params"
                tabindex="4" style = "width:880px;"
                ng-options = "y as y.paramName for y in params" required>
          <option value="">--Select--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


    <div>
    <label style =  "position:relative; left:10px; top:20px">Please Choose One:</label>
    <div  style = "position: relative; left: 200px; top:-13px">
    <div>
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="OverallCompany" id="optionsRadios1" name="optionsRadios" ng-model="recom.radio" required> OverallCompany</div>
    <div>
    <input type="radio" value="Demographics" id="optionsRadios2" name="optionsRadios" ng-model="recom.radio" required>Demographics
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" ng-show="recom.radio=='Demographics'">
    <label style="position: relative; left:10px; top: 28px">Demographics:</label>
    <div style = "position: relative; left:200px">
    <select multiple chosen class="chosen-select" id="demo" ng-model="recom.demo" ng-options = "z as z.demographicName for z in demotype" tabindex="4" style = "width:880px;" required>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```